# Dynamically load external javascript and bind it to a specific DOM element or namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic

I'd like to be able to dynamically load an external javascript file, and then bind methods from the script to specific elements in the DOM.  Is that possible?  How?  With what constraints?

I imagine a solution would look something like this, but I'm open to anything that will work:

```
<html><body>
  <div class="A">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="B">bbbbb</div>
  <div class="A">aaa</div>
</body></html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //This is the internal script, part of the original page
  $.get("url/outside_script.js",
    function(script_obj){
      $(".A").bind('niftyMethod', script_obj.niftyMethod)
    }
  );
</script>
```

Here's the external script: outside_script.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var script_obj = {
    niftyMethod : function(){
      //Do cool stuff in the context of a DOM object.
      $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){$(this).fadeIn(500)});
  }
</script>
```

I've done a good bit of Googling on this, but haven't found much.  Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms...?

NB: I'm happy to use jquery if that's what it takes.

Comment: You don't need the script tag inside your .js file

Comment: Also 'niftymethod' isn't a normal javascript event. If you wanted to invoke script_obj.niftyMethod on click you should use .bind('click', script_obj.niftyMethod)

Comment: Sure.  We could bind the method to a standard event.  The example is a more general case: binding to an arbitrary event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some corrections:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //add script to page
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "url/outside_script.js";
    $('body').append(script);

    //on document ready, bind your function
    $(function(){
        $(".A").bind('click', script_obj.niftyMethod)
    });

</script>
```

External file:

```
var script_obj = script_obj || {
    niftyMethod : function(){
      //Do cool stuff in the context of a DOM object.
      $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){$(this).fadeIn(500)});
  }
```

Comment: This is good.  Is there a way to prevent namespace collisions?  e.g. suppose I already have a script_obj Object defined in the main script.  Is there a way to prevent outside_script from overwriting it?

Comment: whichever comes last will take precedence. I've updated my answer to account for that.